# Xamarin android не подгружаются файлы проекта?

Tags: c#, xamarin

У Xamarin Forms для android проекта хочу разместить изображение по нажатию на кнопку. Для этого в MainPage.xaml - создаю кнопку и вешаю на нею обработчик в MainPage.xaml.cs .

```
 <Button 
        Text="new btn"
        Clicked="OnBTNclicked"></Button>


private void OnBTNclicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Image image = new Image { Source = "1.png" };
            this.Content = image;
        }
```

Все это делаю в `Xamarin_App1.csproj` (который переносимый). Теперь же для добавления картинки мне необходимо саму картинку закинуть в папку целевой платформы - т.е для android это будет папка

> Xamarin_App1.Android.csproj - Resources - drawable .

Закинул туда изображение , но вот в чем проблема: в самих ресурсах студии файл не появился. я уже и приложение пересобирал, и студию заново открывал - результата нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение данной проблемы в имени картинки. Переименуйте ее в "MyImage1.png" и будет Вам счастье. (Файл ресурсов не может понять что "1" это строчное имя картинки, а не ее ID).

> Закинул туда изображение , но вот в чем проблема: в самих ресурсах студии файл не появился

Меня смущает данная фраза. Как Вы добавляете картинку в проект? через проводник компьютера? или через VS?

**Папка -> Добавить -> добавить файл**

Comment: Через проводник

Comment: Спасибо, понял что нужно добавлять файлы через 
 
Папка -> Добавить -> существующий элемент 
, а не напрямую через проводник